# Filter dimension hierarchically

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube

I have a table that holds categories. Categories can be top-level and independent, or they can be a sub-category:

```
MyCategory
  MyCategoryId Int  -- PK
  Name Character Varying 50  -- descriptive "Name" of the category
  ...
  MyParentCategoryId Int NULL  -- Self-referencing PK, NULL means root level
  ...
```

It is referenced by a massive `MyFacts` table:

```
MyFacts
  ...
  MyCategoryId Int  -- Foreign Key
  ...
```

Note that there are only two levels for the category: root (Parent is null) and leaf (Parent points to... the parent.

I make a cube out of it, with MyFacts as my facs and MyCategory as a dimension.

Let's stat with this in the category table:

```
  (1, 'Red', NULL)
  (2, 'Green', NULL)
  (3, 'Tomato', 1)
  (4, 'Strawbery, 1)
  (5, 'Cucumber, 2)
```

The categories will be shown as a number of list boxes in the UI, but I want it to be accessible through direct connections or even web controls for cubes.

Issue: when checking "Red", the cube should return values for "Red", for "Tomato" and for "Strawberry". That's easy enough with a view,

BUT,

I can control and sanitize the input often but not always. I can do a simple second table/view to allow for these categories to be joined, BUT, what if a user checks "Red" AND "Strawberry? All of a sudden there are duplicate items in the source and SQL.

So is there a way to have a hierarchy of member values? I've looked at MDX Descendants() but it doesn't seem to apply. Note that the use case is me setting up this cube, a user going in to Client X, checking "Red" and "Strawberry", and results for "Red", "Strawberry" and "Tomato" show up -- without duplication.

Comment: Could you screenshot the dimension designer so we can see how you setup your dimension? I'm interested in whether you used a parent-child hierarchy or whether you just have a flat list of categories.

Answer (score 0):

If the ampersand is used then it specifies an ID
If the ampersand is not used then it specifies the member name

```
e.g.
[Model and Manufacturer].[Manufacturer].&[1002]
[Model and Manufacturer].[Manufacturer].[Apple]
```